# Android in API 23 Notification class in "setLatestEventInfo" method is not working

Tags: android

setLatestEventInfo()  is not working in API 23 Android please help me 
Android API 23v is not supported **setLatestEventInfo()** why? please suggested me how to do it

Comment: *setLatestEventInfo() is not working in API 23 Android* not working? there is no such method on API 23

Answer (score 2):

As see here [setLatestEventInfo](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html) :

*setLatestEventInfo method is removed from Notification class*

To create `Notification` use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) class as:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MyRemiderService.this);
.....
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. notification_template_icon_bg)
       .setContentTitle("ContentTitle")
       .....
       .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.notification_template_icon_bg, notification);
```